# path not found installing rdflib

Tags: python, installation, rdflib

When I setup, I get:

```
C:\Python27>python Lib\site-packages\rdflib-master\setup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Lib\site-packages\rdflib-master\setup.py", line 64, in <module>
        version = find_version('rdflib/__init__.py')
    File "Lib\site-packages\rdflib-master\setup.py", line 59, in find_version
        for line in open(filename):
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rdflib/__init__.py'
```

The file is there, and I've tried adding the package path to PYTHONPATH; no luck.

So I tried using ez_setup.py, but that chokes on some url that gives it a 404 (trace below).

I've also searched for general installation advice: I find pre-K and postgrad, but nothing that helps me.

```
Downloading http://cheeseshop.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c5-py2.7.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "Lib\site-packages\rdflib-master\ez_setup.py", line 223, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])

  File "Lib\site-packages\rdflib-master\ez_setup.py", line 155, in main
    egg = download_setuptools(version, delay=0)

  File "Lib\site-packages\rdflib-master\ez_setup.py", line 137, in download_setuptools
    src = urllib2.urlopen(url)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 432, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 619, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

We need a bit more info I am afraid. Which version of RDFLib? How are trying to install? 
Can we have the full error message?

The best way is to use "pip", install it somehow: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/1.3.X/installing.html

and then do

```
pip install rdflib
```

This will install the newest RDFLib 3.2.X!

Comment: Well, installing is the problem. I updated the comment with the full error message. I'm getting a different problem with pip. Going to install PyCharm and see if it handles this stuff--tho the point was to learn the mechanics before using a tool that will hide all that.                                                         C:\Python27>python Lib\site-packages\pip-1.2.1\setup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Lib\site-packages\pip-1.2.1\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools

Comment: @user2093804 this eror is caused by missing `setuptools`, the page linked tells you to install `setuptools` or `distribute` first.

Comment: Thanks: PyCharm offered distribute, so I used that. Seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's a strange idea to put the source into `Lib\site-packages` but if you want to install from sources you need to call `setup.py` from the source directory. It complains that `rdflib/__init__.py` doesn't exist because it doesn't exist: note that the path is relative.

Comment: Thanks. Where would you put the source?

Comment: Anywhere, as with any other source.

Comment: Anywhere. OK. Just seems like you thought Lib\site-packages was not the best choice.